# Anúncio "Love this site?" aparece cortado no iPad

Tags: bug, design, divulgação, ipad, mobile

Não tenho certeza como aparece do *desktop*, mas na tableta sai assim:

> [image]

Como se pode ver, o problema é no botão "Registre-se" e o resto do texto abaixo dele. *Bueno*, o título em Inglês também deveria ser traduzido, não?

Comment: Não é só no iPad; por falar nele, [isto](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454/ipad-diversos-sprites-aparecem-cortados-ou-deslocados) também acontece com você?